# Copying a button - Problems with size

Tags: java, android

I honestly have no idea why, but when i copy the LayoutParams from the original button, it comes out diffrent in the copied button. I just want to copy a button, and it has already taken me a week. I can't use setBackground() because it will delete the ripple animation (for some reason).

Here is the problem:

[The current state of the application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x3MSt.png)

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="coś tam"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.366" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/Frame"
        android:layout_width="340dp"
        android:layout_height="519dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.491"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.057">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Nazwa"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            android:text="Nazwa" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/godzinyOtwarcia"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="70dp"
            android:text="godziny otwarcia" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/ulica"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:text="ulica" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/but"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:contextClickable="true"
            android:insetLeft="-13dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            android:insetTop="0dp"
            android:insetRight="-13dp"
            android:insetBottom="0dp"
            android:onClick="butClick"
            android:text="Szczegóły"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            app:rippleColor="#000000" />

    </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The button copying thing:

```
package com.example.aplikacjakolejna;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.ColorStateList;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.ScaleAnimation;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout;
import androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintSet;

public class CreateFrame extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Context context;

    private ViewGroup parentLayout;

    public CreateFrame(Context context, ViewGroup parentLayout) {
        this.context = context;
        this.parentLayout = parentLayout;
    }

    public void LumpexCreateFrame(Button but){   // This is a constructor so the button is somewhere else...

        Button Newbut = new Button(context);


        Drawable buttonDrawable = Newbut.getBackground();
        if (buttonDrawable instanceof RippleDrawable) {
            RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = (RippleDrawable) buttonDrawable;
            rippleDrawable.setColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF")));
        }

        Drawable buttonDrawable1 = but.getBackground();
        if (buttonDrawable1 instanceof RippleDrawable) {
            RippleDrawable rippleDrawable = (RippleDrawable) buttonDrawable1;
            rippleDrawable.setColor(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF")));
        }

        Newbut.setBackground(buttonDrawable);
        but.setBackground(buttonDrawable1);

        Newbut.setText(but.getText());
        Newbut.setTextColor(but.getCurrentTextColor());
        Newbut.setTextSize(14);
        Newbut.setAllCaps(false);
        Newbut.setBottom(but.getBottom());
        Newbut.setTop(but.getTop());
        Newbut.setScaleX(but.getScaleX());
        Newbut.setScaleY(but.getScaleY());
        Newbut.setId(Lumpex.getId());
        Newbut.setElevation(0f);
        Newbut.setStateListAnimator(null);
        Newbut.setGravity(but.getGravity());
        Newbut.setMinimumHeight(but.getMinimumHeight());
        Newbut.setBackgroundTintList(but.getBackgroundTintList());
        Newbut.setLayoutParams(but.getLayoutParams());
        Newbut.setPadding(but.getPaddingLeft(), but.getPaddingTop(), but.getPaddingRight(), but.getBottom());

        parentLayout.addView(Newbut);

        Newbut.setX(but.getX());
        Newbut.setY(but.getY());
        Newbut.setTranslationY(Lumpex.getId() * 300 - 300);
    }


}
```

Also the X coordinate of the button moved for some reason too.

Comment: May you have set `inset` in your XML Button and As far as I can see, there is no public method to set `insets` runtime

Comment: I would really not recommend creating a button in this way.  If you really need to create a layout at runtime, put it into a xml file and inflate the xml.  You'll have more easily maintained code by removing the layout information from the java/kotlin.

Comment: What use case are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to create a button in this way? If you can update your question with this information, I think there will be a better way to do the same, as suggested by @GabeSechan also.